# Handling PHP exceptions the correct way

Tags: php, exception

I'm developing my own PHP framework and my code althought is working like it should, it's getting bigger and bigger; that of course leads to multiple ways for my framework to break, so I have decided it is time to implement Exception handling like any other PHP framework does, that 'nice' error view that tells you what might went wrong.

I have done my research and kind of understand how the Extension PHP default class works, I know that I'm able to extend this class and customize the error messages.

I also know that to trigger an Exception you gotta throw it and catch it with a "try/catch" statement, somethin like this...

```
class MyCustomException extends \Exception()
{
    // My stuff
}

public function dontBeZero($number) 
{
    if ($number == 0) {
        throw new MyCustomException('You gave me zero!!');
    }
}

try {
    dontBeZero(0);
} catch (MyCustomException $e) {
    echo '<pre>';
    $e->getMessage(); 
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

I understand that, but my real question is: How does this popular frameworks such as Laravel, Symfony, etc manage to throw you a pretty message showing you what the error was, where do they keep all the logic that verifies whether it should or should not throw an exception, and most importantly where did they catch them?.

Answer (score 1):

Most frameworks show these errors via a custom error handler. A popular one used by laravel is [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops).

You just need to register it as a custom handler, and you'll see the pretty error pages:

```php
$whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
$whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler);
$whoops->register();
```

Keep in mind, you should disable these on production (so that your stack traces/code isn't exposed).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, using a third party library to solve my problem seems great, yet Im trying to keep my framework as vanilla as possible, for learning propouses.

Answer (score 1):

See the two functions [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [set_exception_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php). These functions allow you to register a callback function which is called when an error or exception occurs.

These callback functions are called by the Php runtime and provided with error details as arguments. The error details include error line number, stack trace, file name and more. The callback function can then format and display this information

Comment: I will research those functions and give it a go, Thank you.